# HTML Javascript Math input on list?

Tags: javascript, html, math

What would be the best way to ask a user for input, that can be used later in a list?
In this code below i have a field, that asks for user to give a result number. What i want it to do is to use the given number (amount_input) and show a multiplied result on the ul-list below.

As example, if i give input 4, in the row "multiply by 4" it would give a result of 16.

Im new to coding, so all kind of help would be appereciated. If the code doesn't show enough information, please ask me.

```js
function other_amount_input() {
  var input = document.getElementById("amount_input").value;
  alert("test sum is " + input);
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:#0E1FA8;">

  <input type="text" id="amount_input">
  <button onclick="other_amount_input()">Submit</button>

  <ul>
    <li>multiply by 4</li>
    <li>multiply by 6</li>
    <li>multiply by 8</li>
  </ul>

  <hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get all `li` elements. I added an "id" on the `ul` so it's easier to target it.
2. Loop over all `li` elements, and calculate the correct sum.
3. Add the new value to the `li` elements during the loop by using `innerHTML`.

---

```
const inputValue = Number(document.getElementById("amount_input").value) || 0;
```

Here I do a check to see if the value an actual number. Otherwise, return 0 to avoid breaking the code.

```
const START_MULTIPLE = 4;
const MULTIPLE_STEP = 2;
```

Try to play around with these values (use the button "Copy code to snippet") to see what they are doing. I call `other_amount_input();` so the starting text on the `li`s are updated automatically based on these two constants. A side effect is that you can add or remove `li` elements, and the code will update accordingly.

```
let multiple = 0, product = 0;
```

It's usually good to break down the code in variables, so it's easier to read. Declaring the variables outside the loop is an optimization so new variables aren't created for each iteration within the loop.

```
// 0 == false while all other values are true
product = (inputValue) ? `: ${multiple * inputValue}` : '';
```

This is a short hand if statement. It's the same as writing:

```
if (inputValue != 0) { 
  product = ': ' + multiple * inputValue';
} else {
  product = '';
}
```

```js
function other_amount_input() {
  const liElements = document.getElementById('output').children;
  const inputValue = Number(document.getElementById("amount_input").value) || 0;
 
  const START_TEXT = 'multiple by';
  const START_MULTIPLE = 4;
  const MULTIPLE_STEP = 2;
  
  let multiple = 0, product = 0;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < liElements.length; i++) {
    multiple = (i * MULTIPLE_STEP) + START_MULTIPLE;
    product = (inputValue) ? `: ${multiple * inputValue}` : '';
    liElements[i].innerHTML = `${START_TEXT} ${multiple}${product}`;
  }
}

other_amount_input();
```

```html
<div>

  <input type="number" id="amount_input">
  <button onclick="other_amount_input()">Submit</button>

  <ul id="output">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>

  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: I found a solution for my problem, but this was better. Thank you for helping, and explaining it to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

*Simple code look like this:*

```html
             <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>View Records</title>
        <style>       
        </style>
        </head> 
        <script>
                  var list4 = [4];
        var list6 = [6];
        var list8 = [8];
        function amount4() {
        var input = document.getElementById("amount_input").value;
        if (input && input > 0) {for(var i=0;i<list4.length;i++){
            var multiple = 1;
            multiple = list4[i] * multiple;
        }
        multiple = multiple * input;
        list4.push(multiple);
        list_multiple4(list4);
        return list4
        }
        }
        function amount6() {
        var input = document.getElementById("amount_input").value;
        if (input && input > 0) {for(var i=0;i<list6.length;i++){
            var multiple = 1;
            multiple = list6[i] * multiple;
        }
        multiple = multiple * input;
        list6.push(multiple);
        list_multiple6(list6);
        return list6
        }
        }
        function amount8() {
        var input = document.getElementById("amount_input").value;
        if (input && input > 0) {for(var i=0;i<list8.length;i++){
            var multiple = 1;
            multiple = list8[i] * multiple;
        }
        multiple = multiple * input;
        list8.push(multiple);
        list_multiple8(list8);
        return list8
        }
        }
        function list_multiple4(list){
         var text = "<li> multiply by " + list.slice(-1)[0]  + "</li>" ;         
         document.getElementById("multiply4").innerHTML = text;
        }
           function list_multiple6(list){
         var text = "<li> multiply by " + list.slice(-1)[0]  + "</li>" ;         
         document.getElementById("multiply6").innerHTML = text;
        }
            function list_multiple8(list){
         var text = "<li> multiply by " + list.slice(-1)[0]  + "</li>" ;         
         document.getElementById("multiply8").innerHTML = text;
        }
         </script>       
        <body style="background-color:#0E1FA8;">        
        <input type="text" id="amount_input">        
        <div>
  <ul>
    <li id="multiply4" onclick="amount4()">multiply by 4</li>
    <li id="multiply6" onclick="amount6()">multiply by 6</li>
    <li id="multiply8" onclick="amount8()">multiply by 8</li>
  </ul>
        </div>   

        </body>
        
        </html>
```

Comment: @tyyppi155.. I think u expected this one

Comment: I appereciate your answer, but unfortunatly its not what i am looking for. 
This code seems to be adding rows to the list. However i am looking for a way to update the value in a list with math. As an example, if the list row has a number 5 as value in it, and i submit a number 4, it will update the value of that list row 5 to be 20, as 4 x 5 is 20.